# Django - Is it OK to load secrets / passwords / dynamic values from a cloud service directly in the settings file

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, google-cloud-platform

I want to load some values in my Django settings file at the time of application startup, dynamically from the cloud, namely :

1. Database password
2. Database IP address

**Is it a good practice to add python code to the settings file to retrieve these values from the cloud ?**

I believe these will be loaded only once, at the time of application startup i.e. they won't adversely affect the performance of my application.

For instance :

```
# ~ settings.py ~

# retrieve data from the cloud, directly in the settings file
db_password   = get_my_secrets()
db_ip_address = discover_db_ip()

# configure the database with these dynamic values
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'PASSWORD': db_password,
        'HOST'    : db_ip_address,
    }
}
```

Here's a related article (shared by @Adiii) : [Django Settings In the Cloud](https://engineering.instawork.com/django-settings-in-the-cloud-aa3fc547a2b4)

Comment: Just wondering, what's the use case these values to be dynamic?

Comment: password rotation without code change & service discovery via dynamic IP

Answer (score 5):

You can have multiple options to load the these configuration without altering the code.

- [AWS secret manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/tutorials_basic.html)
- Dot env file from s3
- Environment variable

**Secrets-manager**

> AWS Secrets Manager helps you protect secrets needed to access your
> applications, services, and IT resources. The service enables you to
> easily rotate, manage, and retrieve database credentials, API keys,
> and other secrets throughout their lifecycle

Using AWS secret Manager you can change/update DB Host or your secret without changing the code. for example

```
    secret_name = "db_password"
    region_name = "us-west-2"
    # Create a Secrets Manager client
    session = boto3.session.Session()
    client = session.client(
        service_name='secretsmanager',
        region_name=region_name
    )
    get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(SecretId=secret_name)
    db_password   = get_secret_value_response
```

[secrets-manager](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/secrets-manager.html)

**Dot ENV with s3**

[Dot ENV](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/) is Reads the key-value pair from `.env file` and adds them to environment variable. It is great for managing app settings during development and in production using 12-factor principles.

Create Dot ENV file with all your secret and place the file on s3, before starting application pull the file from s3 and start application.

```
import os
SECRET_KEY = os.getenv("EMAIL")
db_password = os.getenv("db_password")
```

[Python Dot ENv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/)

Another option can be just using System environment variable.

```
db_password=os.getenv('db_password', default_pass)
```

Comment: How does your python code for secrets manager integrate with the django app ? I wish to know if it is OK to add python code in settings file.

Comment: Yes You can look into this article which have same requirement as above https://engineering.instawork.com/django-settings-in-the-cloud-aa3fc547a2b4 "We went through the steps of setting up AWS parameter store with Django settings and then loading those settings back into our Django applications"